# ANTLR3 throws internal error with java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: antlr3

I tried to use ANTLR3 to build a simple Regexpression parser, but it throws the internal error

Here is the Sample.g

```
grammar Sample;

options {
    memoize=true;
    output=AST;
}

tokens {
    RegExp;
}

RegExpression: 
    '/' (a=~('/' | NL))+ '/'
      -> ^(RegExp[$RegExpression.start, $RegExpression.text] $a+ )
     ;

fragment NL: '\n' | '\r';
ANY : . ;
```

I run the command:
    java -jar antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar -print Sample.g

and it gives this:

```
error(10):  internal error: Sample.g : java.lang.NullPointerException
org.antlr.grammar.v3.DefineGrammarItemsWalker.rewrite_atom(DefineGrammarItemsWalker.java:3896)
```

...
...

**Updated according to comments**

```
grammar Sample{
    memoize=true;
    output=AST;
}

tokens {
    RegExp;
}

regExpression: 
    '/' (a=~('/' | NL))+ '/'
      -> ^(RegExp[$regExpression.start, $regExpression.text] $a+ )
     ;

NL: '\n' | '\r';
```

And here are the errors after running the `java -jar antlr-3.5.2-complete.jar Sample.g`

```
error(10):  internal error: Sample.g : java.lang.NullPointerException
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.getTokenElementST(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:311)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.notElement(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2886)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.element(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2431)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.element(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2446)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.alternative(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2250)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.block(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:1798)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.ebnf(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:3014)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.element(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2495)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.alternative(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:2250)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.block(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:1798)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.rule(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:1321)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.rules(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:955)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.grammarSpec(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:877)
org.antlr.grammar.v3.CodeGenTreeWalker.grammar_(CodeGenTreeWalker.java:518)
org.antlr.codegen.CodeGenerator.genRecognizer(CodeGenerator.java:415)
org.antlr.Tool.generateRecognizer(Tool.java:674)
org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:487)
org.antlr.Tool.main(Tool.java:98)
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of ANTLR? It's almost 5 years since 3.5.2 was last updated. I recommend you use ANTLR4 instead.

Comment: It is a legacy code (being used) so it is not easy to move a big .g file to ANLTR 4

Comment: Someone else is also working on the same legacy code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029954/antlr3-noviablealtexception-and-missingtokenexception Homework, by any chance? Perhaps team up with that user? Not many people answering v3 questions anymore... Good luck anyway!

Comment: @BartKiers v3 is far from dead yet, I see quite some projects around Hadoop still use it, e.g. [Hive](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/parse/HiveParser.g), [Apache Pig](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/parser/QueryParser.g).

Comment: Didn't say it was dead (at least, that isn't what I meant), I'm merely pointing out that many people answering questions here do so for v4. I for one used to answer quite a few v3 questions, but don't use v3 anymore and therefor don't have a quick test setup available on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use a rewrite rule (tree construction) on a lexer rule. That doesn't make sense.

In ANTLR, all rules with name starting with an uppercase letter are lexer rules. The tree construction is used on AST nodes, not on tokens themselves, so you have to use it on parser rules (starting with lowercase letter).

When you do that, keep in mind that your `NL` is a fragment now (you cannot use fragments in parser rules) and make sure your `ANY` token doesn't collide with anything else, i.e. define all needed tokens (`/`, `NL` etc.) and put them above the `ANY` token definition.

Comment: Haha, the tree rewrite rule was something even I without a test setup could have answered/spotted! Good call.

Comment: I have updated the code, but it seems still producing the NullPointerException.

Comment: I can't see how `a=~('/' | NL)` could ever match anything, provided that `NL` and `/` are the only tokens defined in your grammar as posted.

Comment: Could you give me more hints? Basically I am trying to match a regular expression in lexer and would like to transform it to AST